# How to display BSSID from wifiManager.connectionInfo in textView or listView

Tags: android

I am trying to display the network status from current connection similar to ipconfig in windows. I got to the point where I can access the information but I cannot get it to display in a textView or listView other than a toast.

I'm using the following code:

```
wifiManager = this.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
   val wifiInfo: WifiInfo! = wifiManager.connectionInfo;
   if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled == true) {
      Toast.makeText(context: this, text: wifiInfo.bssid, Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

I just cannot get it to display in a textView or listView, whichever is more feasible. Please help, I am new at this, but looking forward to becoming a full time freelance coder soon.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the bssid to a `TextView` by just doing something like:

```
myTextView.settext("Bssid: " + wifiInfo.bssid)
```

One of the first links when searchig for "*Android TextView Tutorial*":

https://abhiandroid.com/ui/textview

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been very helpful, was so close but could never simply it.

Comment: I tried the: textView.setText(Bssid: " + wifiInfo.bssid) but the app crashes once entering that activity. I'm not sure if I have to do something extra like a string in the strings file. I also tried: 

   if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled == true) {
      val bssid: String! = wifiInfo.bssid
      val info = "BSSID $bssid"
      textView.setText(info)  
   }

after the wifiManager code but it crashes also. What do you think is causing the app to crash?

Comment: What kind of crash occurs? Maybe provide some details and open another question.

Comment: i fixed it, while looking at the textView class from android developers, did not realize had to add this: "val mytext: TextView = findviewById(R.id.myText)" inside the onCreate. Then i added the string set up: "myText.setText(res.getString(R.string.myText, wifiInfo.bssid)". Of course, had to set up the placeholder and format on the string resources.